# UIToolBar setting isEnabled from other viewControllers

Tags: swift, uitoolbar, isenabled

I have embedded a toolbar into a few view controllers as shown below. I would like to be able to set the `isEnabled` property on the bar button items from any of the controllers - as an example, let's say by pressing a button. I'm pretty sure I need a reference to the toolbar view controller, or maybe the toolbar itself? I'm a little confused...

I was hoping it would be something like:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let vc = ToolbarViewController()
   vc.settingsButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

But then I crash because vc.settingsButton is nil.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ToolbarViewController will be the first child view controller of the current view controller.
If you change your button method to:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = childViewControllers?.first as? ToolbarViewController
    vc?.settingsButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

It should work, however I encourage you to check out the documentation for UITabViewController, as that is the normal way to do this.

Comment: The project began with a TabViewController until a toolbar seemed a better fit. But then I didn't have access to tabBarController.tabBar.items and the view hierarchy is still a little fuzzy in my head. Anyway, this worked great - thanks!